# Problem with hiding floated divs inside parent's div

Tags: html, css

So, I am trying to make floated divs to hide in parent's div, but it isn't working...
My code:
css:

```
        div.scrollarea {
            overflow: scroll;
            width: 400px;
            float: left;
        }

        div.td {                
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

html:

```
        <div class="scrollarea">
            <div class="td">x1</div>
            <div class="td">x2</div>
            <div class="td">x3</div>
            <div class="td">x4</div>
            <div class="td">x5</div>
        </div>
```

So what I am getting is:
(couldn't upload images because of spam prevention, so here is link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0cH1.png

And what I want to get is to get all of .td's in same row, where horizontal scroll would show up.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the elements *inside their parent*, you will have to make the parent element `relative` positioned and children `absolute` and then use `z-index` to hide children behind the parent something like this:

```
#parentID{
  position: 'relative';        /* required */
  /* more needed styles */
}

#child_element{                /* or class here instead of id */
  position: 'absolute';        /* required */
  z-index:-99;                 /* reqyured */
  /* more needed styles */
}
```

To make children appear, you will have to set their `z-index` property to any value greater than `0`

Answer (score 1):

This is how floating elements behave, when they don't fit, they push down until they do fit (which may not always be at the very left of the next "row" if not everything above has the same height, but that's not a problem in your example)

If you want them to all be in one row, you have to make sure that they're all contained in an element that reserves the width for them all to fit in one row:

```
<div class="scrollarea">
   <div style="width: 500px;">
       <div class="td">x1</div>
       <div class="td">x2</div>
       <div class="td">x3</div>
       <div class="td">x4</div>
       <div class="td">x5</div>
   </div>
</div>
```